# skew symmetric matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:

An $n × n$ matrix A is called skew-symmetric if $A^{T}$ = $−A$. What values of $a, b, c,$ and $d$ now make the following matrix skew-symmetric?

$A = \begin{bmatrix}d&6a-c&6a+2b\\a&0&3-4d\\a+5b&c&0\end{bmatrix}$

So far what I have is:

$A^{T}= \begin{bmatrix}d&a&a+5b\\6a-c&0&c\\6a+2b&3-4d&0\end{bmatrix}$

And $A^{T} = -A$

So whatever constant from $A$ was positive or negative must be opposite sign

I have:

$d = d$

$6a-c=a$

$6a+2b=a+5b$

$3-4d=c$

The problem I am having is solving for two unknown variables. Any suggestions?

Comment: You omitted the sign "-" in all equations.

Comment: Yes but what if for example $6a-c$ was negative in that case $a$ would be positive. Wouldn't it?

Comment: $A=-A^T$ and the diagonal entries of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same, so anything on the diagonal is zero.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you I just don't see/understand how you are saying $d$ is then equal to 0?

Comment: As Maam says: you are ommitting negative signs in your equations. For instance, you should have $d=-d$.

Comment: Thus d = 0, and away I go plugging in values.

Comment: Thank you for the help!